# What's the difference between prepositions: "при" і "за"? Де використовувати прийменник "при", а де - "за"?

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

Are those two interchangeable?

Can I say both:
*За умови* and *При умові* / *За бажання...* and *При бажанні*?

Як обрати поміж:

*За умови* і *При умові* / *За бажання...* і *При бажанні...*?

Чи можна і так, і так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old school linguists ([one](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96/), [two](https://www.ar25.org/article/pryymennyk-pry.html)) insist that only *за* is grammatical: 
*за умови, за потреби, за бажання* (or even *бажаючи*).
I would speculate that their reasoning is elimination of similarities with the Russian language, where *при* is used in this context.

However, classical literature has numerous examples of usage of *при* in the context of conditional relation.

**Словник української мови**, [*«при»*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pry):

14. Is used to denote a phenomenon, event, etc. that acts as a **condition** for something
    Уживається з позначенням явища, події і т. ін., які виступають умовою чого-небудь

    > ***При щирості*** між людьми, **при** глибокій і міцній **симпатії** ніякий риск не страшний! — Леся Українка
    >   *Зітхне стара, **при нагоді** розповівши Тоні щось із тієї давньої давнини* — Олесь Гончар

Note that the first example can be expanded like:

> *при щирості* → *при умові щирості*;

So, the answer would be, **depending on your approach**.
If you are a perfectionist, use only *за умови*.
If you allow yourself stepping off the classical rules, use both.

P.S. It seems to be impossible to provide with a short answer for the first part of the question, *What's the difference between prepositions: “при” і “за”?* as they both have pretty broad ranges of usage, and they overlap for only several contexts, including conditional relations.